# How do I add a letter to the increments column of a knex.js schema?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm looking to add a letter to the front/back of the increments column, to give an ID of I1, I2, I3 etc, rather than just an integer. See migration below.

```
return knex.schema.createTable("ingredients", ingredientsTable => {
    ingredientsTable.increments("ingredient_id").primary();
    ingredientsTable
      .string("ingredient_name")
      .notNullable()
      .unique();
    ingredientsTable.string("ingredient_unit");
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible so long as they index type is an integer. You could potentially change `ingredients_id` to a string, but I think you'd want a pretty compelling case for doing so. It isn't uncommon to use strings as IDs, but normally we'd choose to do that if we were using UUIDs.